# Favicon is no showing in IE on my Angular application hosted on IIS

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, iis, favicon

I have a problem with my favicon not showing in Internet Explorer on my website. It's an Angular 7 application hosted on IIS. I have a dev site and a stage site and the favicon shows up fine at the dev site but not stage site.

Things I have tried/taking consideration of:

- Change the favicon to .png instead of .ico
- Add a link to the favicon between Head tags(not necessary in Angular)
- Favicon is included in assets in angular.json
- Same webconfig files for both sites
- Same code for both sites
- Clear IE cache
- I can access the icon at /favicon.ico

What bothers me is that it works on the dev site which makes me believe it's something on the IIS. 
Anyone have some suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check the html elements, whether the image load success? Based on your description, I try to create a new project, it seems that everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

You could force a favicon refresh using the method below to rule out favicon caching by adding the v=2 parameter

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```